# Python 3: How do I add input and a string to the same line?

Tags: python, string, input

I have to put the input on the same line as the string and can't figure out how.
Here's the code:

```
print('Hello! My name is Awesome Computer.')
print('What is your name?')
name = input()
print('It is good to meet you ' + name + '.')
print('How are you today?')
input()
print('Okay.')
print('I am doing great!')
```

Comment: Consider using `input("What is your name?")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function input() takes in a string to print so you can do this:

```py
name = input("What is your name? ")
```

And it will print the string before taking input without adding a newline

Answer (score 0):

You can put a string into the input function parameters like I did below and it will print the string and get the input on the same line. Also, your second input function call wasn't being saved into a variable.

```
print('Hello! My name is Awesome Computer.')
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('It is good to meet you ' + name + '.')

# don't forget to save your input into a variable 
mood = input('How are you today? ')
print('Okay.')
print('I am doing great!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Hello! My name is Awesome Computer.')
# print('What is your name?')
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('It is good to meet you ' + name + '.')
# print('How are you today?')
input('How are you today? ')
print('Okay.')
print('I am doing great!')
```

Test Results

```
Hello! My name is Awesome Computer.
What is your name? John Doe
It is good to meet you John Doe.
How are you today? Healthy
Okay.
I am doing great!
```